# Using substr_count on results returned from Twitter's API?

Tags: php, json, twitter

I'm trying to count the number of times a certain word is used within the results from Twitter but so far the following isn't working:

```
$recentTweets = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=username');
echo substr_count($recentTweets), 'the');
```

If I use:

```
$number = substr_count(strip_tags($recentTweets), 'the');
```

I get a zero.

I'm thinking it's because the results returned by Twitter isn't properly formatted to be used with 'substr_count' but I'm not sure how to fix it, any help would be appreciated.

If it helps I'm using Abraham's PHP Library.

Comment: What twitter API are you using? Could the API possibly be returning an array instead of a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the twitter url returns json encoded response and you are using [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) on it, so change to :

```
$recentTweets = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=username');
$decoded = json_decode($recentTweets); //to array
//loop thru the $decoded array
//get text content and use substr_count() on it
```